# Apache Spark DAG Visualization in json/text format

Tags: apache-spark, bigdata, hadoop-yarn

I was looking at optimizing some pretty big Apache Spark jobs and observed that the DAG visualization is very complicated to do so for a particular stage.

I cannot understand where the outgoing arrows are off to, with various intersections and guesses/assumption to be made to understand it.

Is the a way I can download a text/json format of the DAG, which would be easier to analyse using vim/text editor?

Answer (score 2):

One answer to your question is to use `.explain` operator, that prints the logical and (with extended flag enabled) physical plans to the console.

```
 val records = spark.
 readStream.
 format("rate").
 load

scala> records.explain

== Physical Plan ==
StreamingRelation rate, [timestamp#0, value#1L]

scala> records.explain(extended = true)

== Parsed Logical Plan ==
StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@4071aa13,rate,List(),None,List(),None,Map(),None), rate, [timestamp#0, value#1L]

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
timestamp: timestamp, value: bigint
StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@4071aa13,rate,List(),None,List(),None,Map(),None), rate, [timestamp#0, value#1L]

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
StreamingRelation DataSource(org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession@4071aa13,rate,List(),None,List(),None,Map(),None), rate, [timestamp#0, value#1L]

== Physical Plan ==
StreamingRelation rate, [timestamp#0, value#1L]
```

The physical plan is the conversion of the DAG, so may be it can help you.

This link could be helpful:

https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/spark-structured-streaming/spark-sql-streaming-Dataset-explain.html